# How to merge few array operators in one ? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to merge operators into one line of code if possible?

```
this.markers = [...new Map(this.markers.map(address => [Number(address.latitude), address])).values()] 
this.markers = this.markers.filter(marker => marker.hasOwnProperty('pointId'))
```

This two line if i can to concate with one ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the Map object in the first line?

Comment: remove duplicate object by latitude and return only unique values

Comment: I don't think `Map` removes duplicates, are you thinking of `Set`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox It will remove those with duplicate *keys*, like objects

Comment: This works well, only I want refactoring, if possible to merge into one line to chain functions.

Comment: I think your code is reasonable, though I'd avoid reassigning `this.markers` multiple times

Comment: I agree. The filter can be chained onto the end of the first line

Comment: I've rolled back your latest edit as it fundamentally changes the question you asked. If you need help with your latest code, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter in advance and then get the mapped result.

```
this.markers = [...new Map(this.markers
    .filter(marker => marker.hasOwnProperty('pointId'))
    .map(address => [+address.latitude, address])
).values()];
```